# Añadir y eliminar posiciones en un ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy desarrollando un pequeño juego de dados, donde el usuario puede lanzar 1, 2, 3 o 4 dados a la vez. En la pantalla aparecen los resultados de esas tiradas, pero además, aparece una pequeña sección donde se ven sólo los 8 últimos resultados de dados que hayan salido, a modo de recordatorio.

Lo que hago es que a medida que voy tirando dados, guardo el resultado de las tiradas en un ArrayList que posteriormente muestro con los últimos 8 resultados de esas tiradas.

Lo hago así:

```
ArrayList<Integer> dadosSalientes = new ArrayList<>();


          switch (dadosEnPantalla){
                    case 1:  // Tira 1 dado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado);  // Añade el resultado

                        if (dadosSalientes.size() > 8) { // Si el tamaño del array es mayor de 8
                            dadosSalientes.remove(0);  // Borra el primer resultado
                        }

                        break;

                    case 2:  // Tira 2 dados
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado

                        if (dadosSalientes.size() > 8) { // Si el tamaño del array es mayor de 8
                            dadosSalientes.remove(0);  // Borra el primer resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(1);  // Borra el segundo resultado
                        }

                        break;

                    case 3: // Tira 3 dados
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado

                        if (dadosSalientes.size() > 8) { // Si el tamaño del array es mayor de 8
                            dadosSalientes.remove(0);  // Borra el primer resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(1);  // Borra el segundo resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(2);  // Borra el tercer resultado
                        }

                        break;

                    case 4:  // Tira 4 dados
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado
                        dadosSalientes.add(resultado); // Añade el resultado

                        if (dadosSalientes.size() > 8) { // Si el tamaño del array es mayor de 8
                            dadosSalientes.remove(0); // Borra el primer resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(1); // Borra el segundo resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(2); // Borra el tercer resultado
                            dadosSalientes.remove(3); // Borra el cuarto resultado
                        }

                        break;
                }
```

Esto funciona "casi" bien. En el ArrayList guardo los resultados de los dados a medida que van saliendo, pero si el arrayList supera los 8 resultados, quiero que se borren los primeros y que siempre tenga los 8 últimos resultados.

Pero no me funciona bien. Los dados se añaden bien con .add, pero por ejemplo las tiradas de 3 o 4 dados, no me borra los primeros resultados del arrayList, sino los primeros de la tirada anterior, lo cual no es lo que pretendo.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Mil gracias!

Comment: Si a un carpintero le das un hacha, seguro que hará bien su trabajo. Si a un carnicero le das la misma hacha, se las apañará decentemente. Si a un mecánico le das esa hacha, poco uso le dará... es culpa del hacha? Yo creo que es cuestión de usar la mejor herramienta en cada caso, y lo que tu buscas es una [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), que ya tiene los métodos `addLast()` para añadir al final y `poll()` para sacar el primero. Si usas la ArrayList, también tienes un método `add(obj, INDICE)` que te podría servir para añadir al final.

Comment: Muchas gracias! La clase LinkedList (que desconocía) con los métodos addLast() para agregar al final y poll() para eliminar al principio me funcionó a la perfección! Viviendo y aprendiendo. Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo meter el codigo del switch en un metodo que reciba como parametro el numero de dados, con ayuda de un ciclo agregas/removes de acuerdo al numero de dados, para asi evitar repetir la misma logica en cada case.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en lugar de borrar los elementos de tu lista, lo que debes hacer es recorrerlos a la izquierda el mismo número de veces que lanzas el dado. Crea una variable GLOBAL que contenga el número de veces que lanzas el dado, para que cada que agregues uno nuevo esta se actualice. Te dejo algo de código en C++ para que te des una idea.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arreglo[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int numero_de_dados = 4;

void recorrer(int numero_de_dados) {
    //Recorre a la izquierda el numero de veces que lanzaste el dado.
    while(numero_de_dados != 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[i+1];
        }
        numero_de_dados--;
    }
}

void agregar(int nuevo_valor) {
    //Comienza a insertar desde el indice que se recorrio en la funcion
    //de arriba, es decir, del numero de lanzamientos hasta 8.
    for(int i = numero_de_dados; i < 8; i++) {
        arreglo[i] = nuevo_valor;
    }
    numero_de_dados++;
}

int main() {
    //Recorre a la izquierda, el mismo numero de veces que lanzaste el dado.
    recorrer(numero_de_dados);
    //Los indices que quedaron desocupados a la derecha, se llenaran 
    //con tus nuevos valores.
    agregar(70);
    agregar(80);
    agregar(90);
    agregar(100);
    //IMPRIMIR ARREGLO
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << arreglo[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

SALIDA

```
PS C:\Users\uidg9784\Documents\GitHub\Cpp> ./Dados.exe
5
6
7
8
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos. Aunque al final opté por otra solución, sí me quedo con la forma de añadir y eliminar usando métodos como propones. Mucho más elegante que repetir líneas como hacía yo. Muchas gracias!